SystemError occurs when adding and subtracting elements on GT in Charm-crypto lib
Code show as below：
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup, ZR, G1, G2, GT, pair
groupObj = PairingGroup('MNT224') 
gt = groupObj.random(GT)
g2 = groupObj.random(GT)
result = gt -g2


Env:
Linux ubuntu22.04 ,
charm-crypt 0.5,
python3.10,
libgmp5.1,
openssl1.0,
ide is vscode.
The error message is as follows：
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/ex/scheme.py", line 284, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/x/ex/scheme.py", line 252, in main
    gt - g2
SystemError: error return without exception set


PBC Library Manual：The GT group is currently implemented as a subgroup of a finite field, so only multiplicative operations should be used for GT.(From:  https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch04s04.html)
So, Charm also can't support this operation.
enter image description here
